# django-tables2 Display non-table data

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-tables2

I'm new to Django and Python and am trying to use django-tables2 1.0.4 in django 1.8.4.

I'm trying to display non-table data and getting the each table line displayed but without data.

This is what I display:
Table Statistics [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOv22.png)

My code:

```
# tables.py
class TotalTable(tables.Table):

    tbl = tables.Column(orderable=True,verbose_name='Table Name')
    tbl_cnt = tables.Column(orderable=True, verbose_name='Table Count')

    class Meta:
        # add class="paleblue: to <table> tag
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue", "type": "dict"}
        fields = ('tbl', 'tbl_cnt')
        sequence = fields
        order_by = ('tbl',)

# views.py
class Totals(View):

    template_name = 'lib/totals.html'

    counts = {'Authors': Author.objects.all().count(),
              .........etc......
              'Titles': Title.objects.all().count()
            }
    table = TotalTable(counts)

    def get(self, request):
        RequestConfig(request).configure(self.table)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'table': self.table})

#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^totals/$', Totals.as_view()),
]
# totals.html
{% extends "lib/base.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% block sidebar %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>Table Statistics</h1>
  {% render_table table %}

{% endblock %}
```

Instead of table name and table count I'm getting '— —'.

Comment: Sheng Fang, I'm not sure I appreciate your edit :-(

Comment: Could you explain what `View` is in `class Totals(View)`

Comment: @letsc    from django.views.generic import View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So reading this page, the format of the data appears to be wrong.

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/table-data.html

Try inserting this into the line immediately after assigning the counts dict:

```
counts = [ { 'tbl': k, 'tbl_cnt': v} for k,v in counts.items() ]
```